# When validating a collection of beans, how can I indicate in the error message, which element of the collection is in error?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a bean which references a collection of other beans. I use `@Valid` to include all referenced beans in the validation.

```
public class MasterBean {
    @Valid
    private Collection<DetailBean> details;
    ... 
}

public class DetailBean {
    private String id;

    @NotBlank(message = "{name_not_blank_message_key}")
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

This works fine so far, the user gets all validation error messages from all `DetailBean` instances. However, the error messages do not contain any indication about which of the instances they are related to. Ideally, the user should see something like "Name of *something* is missing", where *something* is a property (e.g. `id`) of the given instance.
Unfortunately the stock MessageInterpolator allows placeholders for static annotation parameters only (like `{min}`) and does not support the substitution of bean properties.

I've read several related posts, maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226797) being the closest, but none of the suggestions seems to be feasible in my case (besides an own MessageInterpolator implementation - what I'm more than afraid of...).

Some more background: I'm working on a JSF 2 project with the extensive use of RichFaces tags. The bean to be validated is part of the backing bean of a JSF page, validation is triggered by a `<rich:graphValidator>` tag upon form submission. The back-end is Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Is this JSF 1.2 or JSF 2?

Comment: It's JSF 2. (Updated the question.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to interpolate the validated value and you are using Hibernate Validator 4.x you could use the [ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-message-interpolator). It is also a custom MessageInterpolator, but you don't have to implement anything yourself.

Fully customizable rendering (including navigation of bean properties a la Expression Language) will come with Bean Validation 1.1 and Hibernate Validator 5. The features are implemented, but not available yet in a final release. See also [BVAL-223](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-223) and [HV-676](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HV-676).

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of the ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator, although I can't use it directly in my case. The properties I have to validate don't give a good reference to the bean itself for the users (e.g. a String which violates @NotBlank does not help much in the error message).