# JAX-RS Form Validation -Highlight input text field and display validation message

Tags: java, forms, constraints, jax-rs, bean-validation

I have a sample CRUD application, The application used is  a Wine Cellar app. You can search for wines, add a wine to your cellar, update and delete wines. I got it from [RESTful services with jQuery and Java using JAX-RS and Jersey](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-and-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/).

I modified the Wine class to include validation constraints.

```
@NotNull(message='Name must have a value')
private String name;
@NotNull(message='Grapes must have a value')
private String grapes;
```

If the user creates/updates, a wine the errors will be thrown if the name and grape fields are empty. All my validation messages are returned to the browser in json format.

```
public Wine create(Wine wine) {...}
public Wine update(Wine wine) {...}
```

If only one error is thrown, I want to display the correct message to the user and also highlight the field.

How do I get the empty field(name or id) that triggered the error as well as the correct validation message?

Comment: Can you give some more details on how do you invoke validation? Are you doing it yourself or is there some integration with Bean Validation provided by Jersey?

Comment: I'm using Bean Validation. I did some more searching and found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226797/making-javax-validation-error-message-more-specific , it seems similar to what I want to accomplish. I'll review it and update my question, if needed.

Comment: I'm still not sure how Bean Validation is invoked in your case. Are you invoking `javax.validation.Validator` yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about inconsistencies or for lack of clarity.

I used an Web Application Exception Mapper to handle the exceptions. It checks if the error was generated from a web application exception or constraint violation exception.

```
if (exception instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
   Set<ErrorResponse> errorResponses = new HashSet<>();
   for (ConstraintViolation violation : ((ConstraintViolationException) exception).getConstraintViolations()) {
   errorResponses.add(new ErrorResponse(violation.getPropertyPath().toString(),violation.getMessage()));
   }
   builder.entity(new WebApplicationError(errorResponses));
}
```

Also, I checked if was a JsonMapping Exception

```
if (exception instanceof JsonMappingException) {
           ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ValidationMessages");
           Set<ErrorResponse> errorResponses = new HashSet<>();

       for(Reference ref : ((JsonMappingException) exception).getPath()) {
          String className = ref.getFrom().getClass().getName()
                                        .substring(ref.getFrom().getClass().getName()
                                        .lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();                        
          String key = "the.key";
          try {
               message = bundle.getString(key);
          } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
               logger.error(e.getMessage());
          }
               errorResponses.add(new ErrorResponse(ref.getFieldName(), message));
        }
            builder.entity(new WebApplicationError(errorResponses));
    }
```

[JsonMapping Exception](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException.html)

[Constraint Violation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html)